# Calendar date background color disappears on page refresh

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-datepicker

I have used bootstrap datepicker. on page load I call REST api to get the holiday list for that month. I then took out all the dates in an array(Only date). And manually I have written the code to colour the background of the holiday date, It works fine when page gets loaded first time, but if I press 'f5' or 'ctrl+f5' I get all the holidays from database but holiday date background colour disappears, and remain as its default colour.
Code I have written is as follows.

```
var finalHolidayDateListForMonth = new Array();
                        var finalHolidayDateListForMonthComment = new Array();
                        var k=0;
                        for(var i=0 ; i<self.monthlyHolidays.length; i++){
                            var startDate = self.monthlyHolidays[i].holidayStartDate;
                            var endDate = self.monthlyHolidays[i].holidayEndDate;
                            //console.log(i+": startDate: "+startDate+" , end date: "+endDate);
                            //console.log("Before loop: j="+startDate.split("-")[2]+" ,k="+k);
                            for(var j=startDate.split("-")[2] ; j<endDate.split("-")[2] || j==endDate.split("-")[2]; j++){
                                console.log("coming in loop, j="+j+" , k="+k);
                                finalHolidayDateListForMonth[k]=j;
                                finalHolidayDateListForMonthComment[k]=self.monthlyHolidays[i].holidayName;
                                console.log("Holidays found: "+finalHolidayDateListForMonth[k]);
                                k++;
                            }
                        }

                        $("#calendar .datepicker").find("table tbody tr").each(function(){
                            console.log("inside datepicker for each loop");
                            $(this).find("td").each(function(){
                                var m;
                                if(($(this).attr('class')) == 'day' || ($(this).attr('class')) == 'today day' ){
                                    var element = parseInt($(this).html());
                                    for(m=0 ; m<finalHolidayDateListForMonth.length ; m++){
                                        if(element == finalHolidayDateListForMonth[m]){
                                            //$(this).addClass("holiday");
                                            console.log("coloring background");
                                            $(this).wrapInner('<center><div title='+finalHolidayDateListForMonthComment[m]+' data-toggle="tooltip" id=circle></div></center>');                                         
                                            break;
                                        }
                                        //alert("element:"+element+" m:"+m+" array length:"+finalHolidayDateListForMonth.length);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        });
```

Before it looks like this,

[image]

And after refresh this happens,
[image]

Can anyone tell where I am going?
Thank you..!!

Comment: Call your function on document.ready.

Comment: Yes it is being called on pageLoad